# android: use stored value and adding new value to it

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have this code to store a value in my Activity:

```
tv_addzekr.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            nowzekr=nowzekr+1;
            tv_nowzekr.setText(nowzekr+":the score");   
            savecurrentzekr(nowzekr);

        }
    });
```

Then i save nowzekr value with this method :

```
public  void savecurrentzekr (int id){

    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("your_prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.putInt("your_int_key", id);
    editor.commit();    
}
```

and load my stored value with this cod in my activity :

```
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("your_prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int myint = sp.getInt("your_int_key", 0);
    nowzekrr=nowzekr+myint; 
    tv_beforzekr.setText(nowzekrr+":stored value");
```

now i want add previous stored value to new value , means sum old stored value and current entered value, but it always show me last stored value not sum of value , anybody can help me where of my cod is wrong ?
for example if i entered 10 for "nowzekr" , "nowzekrr" is always show 10 , if again i entered 25 for "nowzekr", again "nowzekrr" show 25 and not show 35

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public  void savecurrentzekr (int id){  
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("your_prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putInt("your_int_key", sp.getInt("your_int_key", 0) + id);
    editor.commit();    
}
```

No need to call `clear()` method - value will be automatically replaced.

Comment: i delete it but not working, still it show me any value stored in nowzekr, not sum

Comment: What is `nowzekr`'s value?

Comment: for example if i entered 10 for nowzekr  , nowzekrr is always show 10 , if again i entered 25 for nowzekr, again nowzekrr show 25 and not show 35

Comment: It can happen because you didn't call saving in preferences function, or you are saving `0` value. Can you check it?